# Basic WPF app memory leak issue on startup

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to sharpen up on my C# knowledge, so I'm trying to create an application with a login screen that displays first, and if the admin password is entered, it will open up the MainWindow. I have created the login page in WPF and have entered the below code to display the login screen first:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Window1 window1 = new Window1();

            window1.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working for me. When I hit start, the memory usage starts at around 80MB and continues to climb to around 280MB before it crashes with a **System.StackOverflowException**.

The application also does not show on screen.

What am I doing wrong? I have only been learning WPF and C# for a couple of weeks so your feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: You are creating a new `Window1` in the constructor of `Window1`, that is an infinite loop.

Comment: `Window1` must be created and shown outside of itself

Comment: Ah I think I understand. Should I place this within MainWindow?

Comment: Can i ask why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove this two lines

```
Window1 window1 = new Window1(); 
window1.ShowDialog();
```

In the window1.ShowDialog() you are again creating an object and invoking Window1, which goes into infinite loop, hence the System.StackOverflowException is thrown

Comment: Thanks. This works, however it doesn't display the mainwindow in the background.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, this code is an infinite loop. Notice how every constructor call creates another constructor call before it finishes it's execution, if you're new to C# / coding, than I suggest you learn about the stack and why stack overflow occurs here.

I think what you want to do is either set the login window to be the main window and change the main window later, or have the main window show the password prompt window and only show itself after the prompt window. It would help if you add the code for `MainWindow` as well. You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.mainwindow?view=netcore-3.1#remarks).